# Android NDK - getFieldID results in NoSuchFieldError

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've been struggling with this for quite a while and am at wit's end. Basically I'm including a library that has a native component into our Android app.

In the init method of one of the native classes, the init contains the following:

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass(kClassPathName);
if (clazz == NULL) {
    return;
}

fields.context = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "mNativeContext", "I");
if (fields.context == NULL) {
    return;
}
```

The GetFieldID call always throws the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "I" field "mNativeContext" in class "Lcom/test/NativeLibrary;" or its superclasses
```

Followed by a long stack trace (omitted because it's not useful).
The class it reports is the correct fully qualified name of the class.

I've confirmed that there is indeed a `private int mNativeContext` in the class in question.

Things I've tried:

- making the field public
- disabling proguard obfuscation
- compiling the library with javac 1.6 instead of 1.7 (it was originally developed targeting 1.6, so I thought that perhaps a compiler difference was causing the problem).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ¿ǝpoɔ ɹnoʎ ʇsod noʎ uɐɔ

Comment: Unfortunately there's not a whole lot more code to post; this happens as soon as the Java class that interfaces with the native class is instantiated, as it calls the native `init()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was Proguard all along. I must have done something incorrectly the first time I tried to keep the symbols around. If you run into this problem, try adding something like this into your proguard.cfg:

```
# Don't rename any Java class members that are accessed by name from native code!
-keep class com.test.NativeLibrary {
    *** mNativeContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your kClassPath is wrong. I don't use a hard-coded path, and
instead pull the class from the jCaller argument, which I use as the
first argument to all my native functions.

Here is a code snippet I use that writes integer values back into the
Java class. First the Java class:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Mp3 {
  public int mDecodeSampleRate= 8000;
  public int mDecodeChnlCt= 1;
  public int mDecodeByteCt;

  //Interface to Mp3 native library.
  private native int nDecodeBlock(Mp3 mp3, int hDecoder, ByteBuffer src, int srcOffset, int srcCt, ByteBuffer dst);

  public int decodeBuf(ByteBuffer src, int srcOffset, ByteBuffer dst) {
    int consumeCt= 0;
    consumeCt = nDecodeBlock(this, mDecoder, src, srcOffset, src.capacity(), dst);
    //SampleRate, ChnlCt, and ByteCt will have been updated.
    return(consumeCt);
  }

  public int decodeGetSampleRate() { return (mDecodeSampleRate); }
  public int decodeGetChannelCt() { return (mDecodeChnlCt); }
  public int decodeGetAudioByteCt() { return (mDecodeByteCt); }
}
```

Now the JNI C code:

```
static void SetObjInt(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, char *Name, int Val) {
  jclass objClass;
  jfieldID fieldID;
  if(!(objClass= (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj))) {
    LOGE("Unable to obtain objClass(%s)!",Name);
  } else if(!(fieldID= (*env)->GetFieldID(env,objClass,Name,"I"))) {
    LOGE("Unable to obtain field ID(%s).",Name);
  } else {
    //LOGD("Setting %s",Name);
    (*env)->SetIntField(env,obj,fieldID,(jint)Val);
  }
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_acme_mp3_nDecodeBlock(
  JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject jCaller,
  jint jDecoder,
  jobject jSrc, jint SrcOffset, jint SrcByteCt,
  jobject jDst
) {
  void *hDecoder= (void*)jDecoder;
  unsigned char *pSrc= (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,jSrc);
  short *pDst= (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,jDst);
  int ConsumedCt= 0;
  int DstCt= 0;
  mp3_info_t Info;

  ConsumedCt= mp3_decode(hDecoder,(void*)&pSrc[SrcOffset],SrcByteCt-SrcOffset,(short*)pDst,&Info);
  if(ConsumedCt>0) {
    SetObjInt(env,jCaller,"mDecodeSampleRate",Info.sample_rate);
    SetObjInt(env,jCaller,"mDecodeChnlCt",Info.channels);
    SetObjInt(env,jCaller,"mDecodeByteCt",Info.audio_bytes);
  }
  return(ConsumedCt);
}
```

Comment: I found these two pages very helpful: [JNI Tutorial](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html#zz-5.1) and [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html).

Comment: At the risk of down-voting myself, I just realized I am casting a pointer to an int myself (hDecoder), so that is probably not the problem. I think your kClassPath may be suspect (What the 'L' is that?). I just pull the class from the jCaller arg (which is added by JNI and always present).

Comment: Correction: jCaller is an argument I add, just a self-reference to my Java object that makes it fool-proof to derive the class name.  (Good thing I re-read my posts.)

Comment: That's what I thought initially too; but if `kClassPath` was incorrect, then why would the `FindClass` call succeed? It uses the exact same argument as the call to `GetFieldID` that throws the exception.